# Exporting Certificates from AWS Certmanager Boto3 Python310

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3

So I manually imported a certificate and key pair issued by a third party to certmanage in AWS and I am trying to programaticly export to a webserver and I get this error:

botocore.errorfactory.ValidationException: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the ExportCertificate operation: Certificate ARN: arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:x:certificatexxxxxxxx is not a private certificate

Can I export a third party cert and private key from AWS certmanager?

python -V
Python 3.10.0

I am trying to export a AWS managed certificate from certmanager and its failing.

I've  tried googleing the error code but come up with nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AWS Certificate Manager (ACM) has two types of certificates. Public and Private.

You can't export any certificate when it is public. Even if you imported it.

You can associate your ACM certificate with ALB, for example, and put this ALB in front of your EC2 instance. But you can't export.

As you imported the certificate, it means you have the public and private parts of the certificate. You can just use it on your instance.

Only ACM privates ones can be exported.

Comment: Thank you for the update. I was hoping to use the ACM as a cert store to help keep track of all our third-party certificates. Is there something I could use as secure storage in AWS, or should I look to use hashicorp vault for this type of storage?

Comment: You can use AWS Secrets Manager to store your certificate data, private and public.

Comment: Yeah, that's annoying because I want to keep track of when these third-party certs expire as well. I guess could just import them into the cert store at the same time I deploy new ones.